# Call PHP from Cacheable Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I wrote some PHP to query the live status of a Youtube channel. Instead of polling Youtube, I poll an API endpoint (JSON) of a Youtube Live Embed plugin for the "live_status" marker.

As another wrinkle to this, the result of the API polling and the current time is overwritten to a JSON file (called: LastEmbedVidioPull.json in my code below), so that on subsequent runs of the PHP, the code will check the LastEmbedVidioPull.json to see whether 5 minutes have elapsed since the last run. If not, the PHP will echo the status code from LastEmbedVidioPull.json. If 5 or more minutes have elapsed, then we poll the external API endpoint, update the internal JSON file with the new time and status code, and echo the new status code. There's also error logging, and the default status code 0 (not live) is echoed when an error is present.

The PHP:

```
<?php

$now = date("Y-m-d") . "T" . date("H:i:s.000") . "Z";
$curla = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curla, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "[URL to LastEmbedVidioPull.json]",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
]);

$responsec = curl_exec($curla);
$errora = curl_error($curla);

curl_close($curla);

if ($errora) {
    $toLog = $now . " cURL error #: " . $errora . "\r\n";
    $Log = "EmbedVidioErrorLog.txt";
    $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
    $save_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $Log;
    file_put_contents($save_path, $toLog, FILE_APPEND | LOCK-EX);
    echo 0;
} else {
    $showInfoa = json_decode($responsec, true);
    $lastpull = strtotime($showInfoa["pull_time"]);
    $diff = strtotime($now) - $lastpull;
    if ($diff > 300) {

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "[URL to External API endpoint provided by YT Live Embed Plugin Provider]",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $error = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($error) {
            $toLoga = $now . " EmbedVidio API cURL error #: " . $error . "\r\n";
            file_put_contents($save_path, $toLoga, FILE_APPEND | LOCK-EX);
            echo 0;
            
        } else {
            ##echo $response;
            $extractInfo = str_replace('},]',"}]",$response);
            $showInfo = json_decode($extractInfo, true);
            $live_status = $showInfo["live_status"];
            $responsea = json_encode('{"live_status":"' . $live_status . '", "pull_time":"' . $now . '"}');
            file_put_contents($upload_dir['basedir'] . '/LastEmbedVidioPull.json', $responsea, LOCK-EX);
            echo $live_status;
        }
    } else {
        echo $showInfoa["live_status"];
    }
}
?>
```

I haven't tried the PHP yet, so I'm not sure about performance, and I'm definitely open to suggestions. Additionally, you will see I am echoing a status code (whether a static 0 for errors or a 0 or 1 from either JSON file). But, how would I go about connecting cacheable JS to get the output from my PHP, so it can use the status code to add or remove a "we're live" banner to the top of the webpage?

Comment: Why not echo JSON and then use fetch from the client

Comment: @mplungjan - so on all of the echos, something like this? echo json_encode('{"live_status":' . $live_status . ')'; and client side, would I want to use ajax?

Comment: Yes. `fetch` is AJAX